# Blank chart when using candlesticks

Tags: c#, oxyplot

When trying to plot candlestick chart using Oxyplot library, it is empty, despite the fact that I assigned model to the plot view.

```
var plotModel1 = new PlotModel { Title = "Large Data Set (wide window)" };

var timeSpanAxis1 = new DateTimeAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom };
plotModel1.Axes.Add(timeSpanAxis1);
var linearAxis1 = new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left };
plotModel1.Axes.Add(linearAxis1);
var n = 10000;
var items = HighLowItemGenerator.MRProcess(n).ToArray();
var series = new CandleStickSeries
{
    Color = OxyColors.Black,
    IncreasingColor = OxyColors.DarkGreen,
    DecreasingColor = OxyColors.Red,
    DataFieldX = "Time",
    DataFieldHigh = "H",
    DataFieldLow = "L",
    DataFieldOpen = "O",
    DataFieldClose = "C",
    TrackerFormatString =
                         "High: {2:0.00}\nLow: {3:0.00}\nOpen: {4:0.00}\nClose: {5:0.00}",
    ItemsSource = items
};

timeSpanAxis1.Minimum = items[n - 200].X;
timeSpanAxis1.Maximum = items[n - 130].X;

linearAxis1.Minimum = items.Skip(n - 200).Take(70).Select(x => x.Low).Min();
linearAxis1.Maximum = items.Skip(n - 200).Take(70).Select(x => x.High).Max();

plotModel1.Series.Add(series);

timeSpanAxis1.AxisChanged += (sender, e) => AdjustYExtent(series, timeSpanAxis1, linearAxis1);

var controller = new PlotController();
controller.UnbindAll();
controller.BindMouseDown(OxyMouseButton.Left, PlotCommands.PanAt);

plotView1.Model = plotModel1;
```

Strange thing is that I've just copied few things from the [Oxyplot series example](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/Examples/ExampleLibrary/Series/FinancialSeries/CandleStickSeriesExamples.cs). I've also created [minimal project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/arhggxh0s4ny6yv/MyStrategies.zip?dl=0) with the problem described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objects generated by the `HighLowItemGenerator` have different names of properties than defined in the `CandleStickSeries` definition. Check the `items` objects in the debugger to see it. Maybe the sample is a bit out of date. The solution is to change the series definition to use the correct properties this is how it should look like:

```
var series = new CandleStickSeries
{
      Color = OxyColors.Black,
      IncreasingColor = OxyColors.DarkGreen,
      DecreasingColor = OxyColors.Red,
      DataFieldX = "X",
      DataFieldHigh = "High",
      DataFieldLow = "Low",
      DataFieldOpen = "Open",
      DataFieldClose = "Close",
      TrackerFormatString =
                           "High: {2:0.00}\nLow: {3:0.00}\nOpen: {4:0.00}\nClose: {5:0.00}",
      ItemsSource = items
};
```

Comment: That works. Do you happen to also know why "High" in `TrackerFormatString` always shows 0?

Comment: @Pablo Hi, did you solve the TrackerFormatString problem for "High" value? I've faced same issue, its always shows 0 when I hover my mouse on the candlestick chart.